# Multi-line regex - issue capturing repeated groups

Tags: regex, pcre, multiline

So I am trying to look at the following text:

```
This is some header 1

nonsense text 1


Repeated item 1
Repeated item 1 Data

nonsense text 1


Repeated item 2
Repeated item 2 Data

This is some header 2

nonsense text 1

Repeated item 1
Repeated item 1 Data

nonsense text 1

Repeated item 2
Repeated item 2 Data
```

I am trying to capture the repeated items and also capture the digit in the header preceding them like so:

```
This is some header 1
Repeated item 1
Repeated item 1 Data
Repeated item 2
Repeated item 2 Data

This is some header 2
Repeated item 1
Repeated item 1 Data
Repeated item 2
Repeated item 2 Data
```

I have no issues capturing the repeated items using this:

```
Repeated Item ([0-9]+)\sSome item data: (.*)
```

However, for each repeated item, I also want to capture the header before it like this( but this regex doesn't work ):

```
This is some header ([0-9]+).*Repeated Item ([0-9]+)\sSome item data: (.*)
```

I also tried the following regex which is a derivative of the one just above this text:

```
(?sm)This is some header ([0-9]+).*Repeated Item ([0-9]+)\sSome item data: (.*)
```

However, the regex above captures only the first header and the least repeated item. Is there a way to achieve what I am trying to achieve with just a regex expression? I can obviously manually parse the text line by line but I am hoping I can achieve this with a regex.

Comment: Doing that *with just a regex expression* is just stupid, parsing the text by line is from far a better approach. Don't waste your time with that.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, can you elaborate on why using a regex to accomplish this is a stupid idea? I do appreciate you commenting but it adds little value to just say that an approach is stupid without giving an explanation on why approach A is better than approach B.

Comment: Please add example of what you are trying to capture. Every line that includes `Repeated item` or not?

Comment: @dawg, I just added a little more description on what I am trying to look for and how I am trying to group it.

Comment: @GeorgiAngelov: because doing it by line keeps the code simple (and eventually offers the possibility to work with streams, filters, to not fully load a file), when a full regex approach will end with an unnecessary complicated pattern to obtain the result you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated for your example:

```
/^(This is some header \d+)[\s\S]+?^(Repeated item \d+)\s*^(Repeated item.*)[\s\S]+?(Repeated item \d+)\s*^(Repeated item.*)/m
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lK4NQg/4/)

Perl example:

```
$ txt='This is some header 1
> 
> nonsense text 1
> 
> 
> Repeated item 1
> Repeated item 1 Data
> 
> nonsense text 1
> 
> 
> Repeated item 2
> Repeated item 2 Data
> 
> This is some header 2
> 
> nonsense text 1
> 
> Repeated item 1
> Repeated item 1 Data
> 
> nonsense text 1
> 
> Repeated item 2
> Repeated item 2 Data'

$ echo "$txt" | perl -0777 -lne 'while (/^(This is some header \d+)[\s\S]+?^(Repeated item \d+)\s*^(Repeated item.*)[\s\S]+?(Repeated item \d+)\s*^(Repeated item.*)/gm) {print "$1\n$2\n$3\n$4\n$5\n\n" }'
This is some header 1
Repeated item 1
Repeated item 1 Data
Repeated item 2
Repeated item 2 Data

This is some header 2
Repeated item 1
Repeated item 1 Data
Repeated item 2
Repeated item 2 Data
```

---

A more robust approach is to break down the text into blocks first and then separate out the repeating items.

Comment: you nailed it. Thank you.

Comment: would this be possible if we do not know the number of times a block is repeated? The block being ("Repeated item2\nRepeated 2 Data") ? It seems the query does depend on this sequence repeated twice each time.